# Pointer type casting altering unintended memory

Tags: c++

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 20

float DataSource[ARRAY_SIZE];

void Read(unsigned char const *Source, unsigned char *Destination, unsigned long DataSize)
{
  for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < DataSize; i++)
  {
    *(Destination + i*DataSize) = *(Source + i*DataSize);
  }
}

void fun()
{
  int Index;
  float Dest;

  for ( Index = 0; Index < ARRAY_SIZE; Index++ )
  {
    Read((unsigned char *)&DataSource[Index], (unsigned char *)&Dest, sizeof(DataSource[Index]));
  }
}
```

I'm having an issue with the above code where upon calling Read(), my Index variable gets overwritten and I am certain the ugly pointer casting is the culprit, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what is happening here.

The unsigned char pointer types are mandatory because the above code is intended to simulate some driver level software and maintain the same prototype.

Can someone help me to understand the issue here? All the above code is changeable except for the prototype of Read().

Comment: Why are you multpilying `i` by `DataSize` inside `read`??? What is `*(Destination + i*DataSize) = *(Source + i*DataSize)` supposed to do?

Comment: A float is 4 bytes (typically), so `(unsigned char*) &DataSource[Index]` is sending a pointer to the first byte of the float. If that helps you understand a bit more about what is going on.

Comment: Also, what's with the `unsigned long i`. If sizeof(float) is that big, you have some crazy precision going on.

Comment: Yeah, there was some thoughtless copy/pasting there. Unsigned long i is ridiculous and unintended. I was trying to write byte-by-byte and see now that I was doing nothing of the sort. Thanks for the quick replies everybody.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < DataSize; i++)
{
  //              vvvvvvvvvv               vvvvvvvvvv
  *(Destination + i*DataSize) = *(Source + i*DataSize);
}
```

`i * DataSize` is always greater than `i` => "out of bound" access.

Replace with:

```
for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < DataSize; i++)
{
  *(Destination + i) = *(Source + i);
}
```

Comment: That was certainly my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You pass in a single `float`'s address to `Read`  (`&Dest`) and then proceed to write many valuese to consecutive memory locations. Since you're writing random memory at that point it's not unlikely that it could have overwritten `index` (and other stuff) because stacks usually grow downwards.

Comment: Writing to consecutive bytes would be fine.  But he isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
*(Destination + i*DataSize) = *(Source + i*DataSize);
```

You want to copy `DataSize` adjacent bytes, not bytes `DataSize` apart (total span `DataSize*DataSize`)

Just say

```
Destination[i] = Source[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

An amusing (to me) C++ way.

```
template<typename Data>
struct MemBlockRefHelper {
  typedef Data value_type;
  Data* data;
  size_t size;
  MemBlockRefHelper( Data* d, size_t s):data(d), size(s) {}

  template<typename Target, typename Other=typename Target::value_type>
  Target& Assign( MemBlockRefHelper<Other> const& other ) {
    Assert(size == other.size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      if (i < other.size) {
        data[i] = other.data[i];
      } else {
        data[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    Target* self = static_cast<Target*>(this);
    return *self;
  }

};
struct MemBlockRef;
struct MemBlockCRef:MemBlockRefHelper<const unsigned char> {
  MemBlockCRef( const unsigned char* d, size_t s ):MemBlockRefHelper<const unsigned char>( d, s ) {}
  MemBlockCRef( const MemBlockRef& other );
};
struct MemBlockRef:MemBlockRefHelper<unsigned char> {
  MemBlockRef( unsigned char* d, size_t s ):MemBlockRefHelper<unsigned char>( d, s ) {}
  MemBlockRef& operator=( MemBlockRef const& other ) {
    return Assign< MemBlockRef >( other );
  }
  MemBlockRef& operator=( MemBlockCRef const& other ) {
    return Assign< MemBlockRef, const unsigned char >( other );
  }
};
inline MemBlockCRef::MemBlockCRef( const MemBlockRef& other ): MemBlockRefHelper<const unsigned char>( other.data, other.size ) {}

void Read( unsigned char const* Source, unsigned char* Dest, unsigned long DataSize ) {
  MemBlockCRef src( Source, DataSize );
  MemBlockRef dest( Dest, DataSize );
  dest = src;
}
```

massively over engineered, but the idea is to wrap up the idea of a block of POD memory of a certain size, and provide reference semantics to its contents (initialization is creating a new reference to the same data, assignment does a copy over the referred to data).

Once you have such classes, the code for `Read` becomes a 3 liner.  Well, you can do it in one:

```
  MemBlockRef( Dest, DataSize ) = MemBlockCRef( Source, DataSize );
```

but that is needless.

Well, so it this entire framework.

But I was amused by writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a closer look at your `Read()`: i changes from 0 to DataSize-1; each time you access memory by an offset of i*DataSize... that is, by an offset from 0 to DataSize*(DataSize-1). Looks wrong, as `DataSize**2-DataSize` makes no sense.

Unlike other answers, I don't want to guess what you wanted. Just showing a kind of "dimensional analysis" that can help spotting the wrongest part of code *without* reading the author's mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the scalar variable `Dest` declared inside `fun()` as an array inside `Read()`. It seems that both `Dest` and your `Index` variable are placed adjacent on the stack which explains that `Index` gets overwritten exactly when the loop inside `Read()` is executed for `i==1`.

So the solution is: declare `Dest` as an array, too:

```
float Dest[ARRAY_SIZE];
```